# Proving equality of sets using proof by contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering how can I prove the following conjecture using proof by contradiction.

If $A-B = B-A$, then it must be the case that $A=B$.

I tried to assume that $A \ne B$ and tried to show that $A-B = B-A$ still holds. However, I'm not sure how to deduce this part. 
I am new to set theory and proofs, so any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that $A-B\subseteq A$?  That would imply since $B-A=A-B$ that $B-A\subseteq A$ as well.  What elements could possibly be in $B-A$ which are also in $A$?  We learn that $A-B=B-A$ implies that $A-B=B-A=\emptyset$.  Can you reach a conclusion from this?

Comment: As for explicitly wording this as proof by contradiction., suppose that $A\neq B$.  That means that at least $A\not\subseteq B$ or that $B\not\subseteq A$.  Without loss of generality, suppose the first.  That means that there is some element of $A$ which is not an element of $B$, let's call it $a$.  Then $a\in A-B$.  Is it possible for $a$ to also be in $B-A$?  It should have been given our hypothesis... but what does it mean to be in $B-A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to assume that $A≠B$ and tried to show that $A−B=B−A$ still holds. However, I'm not sure how to deduce this part.

Suppose there is an $a$ such that $a\in A$ and $a\notin B,$ yet $A-B = B-A$

$a\in A-B, a\notin B-A$

$A-B \ne B-A$

Contradiction!

All $a$ in $A$ are also in $B.$

And by an identical argument all $b$ in $B$ are also in $A.$

---

Alternatively, and a little longer for clarity.

- Assume $A\smallsetminus B=B\smallsetminus A$.

  - Take an arbitrary $a$

    - Assume $a\in A$.

      - Assume $a\notin B$.
      - $a\in A \wedge a\notin B$ by conjunction .
      - $a\in A\smallsetminus B$ by definition of set minus.
      - $a\in B\smallsetminus A$ by the first assumption (and substitution).
      - $a\in B\wedge a\notin A$ by definition of set minus.
      - $a\in B$ by simplification.
      - Contradiction! ($a\notin B$ and $a\in B$)
    - $a\in B$ via proof by contradiction.
  - $a\in A\to a\in B$ via conditional proof
- $\forall x~(x\in A\to x\in B)$ by universal generalisation.
- $A\subseteq B$ by definition of subset
- $B\subseteq A$ similarly.
- $A=B$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused about how all $a$ in $A$ are also in $B$. Isn't it the case that since $a \in A-B$, then $a \in A$ but $a \notin B$ based on the set difference definition?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain your steps in a little further detail, please?

Comment: I added a line.  If $a\in A$ and $a\notin B$ then $A-B \ne B-A$ creating a contradiction.  Hence, all $a\in A$ are also in $B.$